# Is there any way to prevent the onCreate from calling once the child value has been changed in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, oncreate

I want to change the text in the Text View when the data is changed in the Firebase. However, the result I want is just the change in the TextView, but it ends up to be the onCreate method is called again. So what are steps in order to prevent the method from calling when data is changed?

I have tried to run it in the new thread and handler, but the result is still the same.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
      Log.e("onCreate","oncreate");

      DatabaseReference statusRDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child(friendID).child("CurrentStatus");
        statusRDB.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String status = dataSnapshot.child("Status").getValue().toString();
                String lastActive = dataSnapshot.child("LastActive").getValue().toString();
                mStatusText.setText(showActive.showActiveTime(status,lastActive));

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

}
```

This is the log after the child is changed. as we can see, the activity is paused, then it will be created again.

```
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 11975
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 54071124
D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=11975, ga_screen_class(_sc)=ChatActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=4408365996041177143}]
V/FA: onActivityCreated
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 54071174
D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{8a14704 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, ga_previous_class(_pc)=ChatActivity, ga_previous_id(_pi)=4408365996041177143, ga_screen_class(_sc)=ChatActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=4408365996041177144}]
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
    Connection attempt already in progress
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@204ceb1 time:31322606
D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 18053
    Connecting to remote service
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 54089226
D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=18053, ga_screen_class(_sc)=ChatActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=4408365996041177144}]
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 54089635
D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, ga_previous_class(_pc)=ChatActivity, ga_previous_id(_pi)=4408365996041177144, ga_screen_class(_sc)=FriendProfile, ga_screen_id(_si)=4408365996041177142}]
D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
    Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 39
    Connection attempt already in progress
    Activity paused, time: 54089644
V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{5820612 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4d012e7 {com.example.user.convo/com.example.user.convo.profile.FriendProfile}} show : true
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 5
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@4d012e7 time:31340945
E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
D/FA: Application going to the background
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/FA: Logging event (FE): app_background(_ab), Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto}]
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 87634(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 28(748KB) LOS objects, 11% free, 39MB/44MB, paused 1.322ms total 114.785ms
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

The result expected is only the text in the Text View will be changed instead of the whole onCreate being called and start a new activity.

Comment: There is no `onCreate` in the code you shared, so it's hard to say why it'd be triggered again. Also note that the code you shared uses `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`, which will only be triggered once.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Actually I think the `onCreate` is having error because when the data is changed, the log will be called. So I think, there must be something triggering the `onCreate`. Besides, I have tried `addValueEventListener`, but it ends up the same.

Comment: How do you see that onCreate method is called again?

Comment: I use  `log.e("onCreate",onCreate);`. So that means when the activity is created, the log will be called. And in my case, when the data is changed, the onCreate log is repeating.

Comment: "the onCreate log is repeating" There is no way the Firebase listener can be causing this. Are you sure your app isn't crashing or something similar? In that case the app would restart and thus the `onCreate` would be called again. If this is the case, have a look in the logcat output for the cause of the crash.

Comment: But actually the activity is not crashing, it just creates a new activity and left the old one behind.

Answer (score 0):

There will not be call oncreate method again in above sudo code. in above code your're using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` which will only be call for once.